# WebM Spritesheet/Transcode from canonical config failed in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

WebM Spritesheet/Transcode from canonical config failed to complete with error message: Request field config.editList[0].startTimeOffset is 0s, expected start time less than the minimum duration of all inputs for this atom (0s).

The config used is from https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/generate-spritesheet#generate_image_periodically

Project Number: PROJECT-NUMBER

Job ID: projects/PROJECT-NUMBER/locations/us-central1/jobs/JOB-ID

Location: us-central1

Job Config

```
{
  "name": "projects/PROJECT-NUMBER/locations/us-central1/jobs/JOB-ID",
  "config": {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "key": "input0",
        "uri": "gs://input_video.webm"
      }
    ],
    "editList": [
      {
        "key": "atom0",
        "inputs": [
          "input0"
        ],
        "startTimeOffset": "0s"
      }
    ],
    "elementaryStreams": [
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h264",
          "profile": "high",
          "preset": "veryfast",
          "heightPixels": 360,
          "widthPixels": 640,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "bitrateBps": 550000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "crfLevel": 21,
          "vbvSizeBits": 550000,
          "vbvFullnessBits": 495000,
          "gopDuration": "3s",
          "entropyCoder": "cabac",
          "frameRate": 60
        },
        "key": "video-stream0"
      },
      {
        "audioStream": {
          "codec": "aac",
          "bitrateBps": 64000,
          "channelCount": 2,
          "channelLayout": [
            "fl",
            "fr"
          ],
          "sampleRateHertz": 48000
        },
        "key": "audio-stream0"
      }
    ],
    "muxStreams": [
      {
        "key": "sd",
        "fileName": "sd.mp4",
        "container": "mp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "video-stream0",
          "audio-stream0"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "output": {
      "uri": "gs://output/"
    },
    "spriteSheets": [
      {
        "format": "jpeg",
        "filePrefix": "small-sprite-sheet",
        "spriteWidthPixels": 64,
        "spriteHeightPixels": 32,
        "startTimeOffset": "0s",
        "interval": "7s",
        "quality": 100
      },
      {
        "format": "jpeg",
        "filePrefix": "large-sprite-sheet",
        "spriteWidthPixels": 128,
        "spriteHeightPixels": 72,
        "startTimeOffset": "0s",
        "interval": "7s",
        "quality": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  "state": "FAILED",
  "failureReason": "Job validation failed: Request field config.editList[0].startTimeOffset is 0s, expected start time less than the minimum duration of all inputs for this atom (0s).",
  "ttlAfterCompletionDays": 30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the duration we're calculated for the input is 0 seconds. So either the input is empty, or we're unable to calculate the duration of the input. Do you know if the former is the case? For the latter, if the customer provides an endTimeOffset in their editList, then we should use that duration, which would get past this validation error.

Totally missed the input link in comment#1, sorry about that! So when I run ffprobe on the input, I get

```
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
```

We do generate the editList, but in this case we couldn't get valid duration from the input. My guess is that this worked previously because the inputs used contained timing metadata, though I could help confirm that if you have the input from a job that went through successfully. I'd suggest specifying the endTimeOffset in the job config if possible (especially if different encoding is used from input-to-input).